# Load Runner error short term filter must be empty

Tags: load-testing, loadrunner

I have a problem in Load runner.
upon using "Web_add_filter" function an internal error says that "short term filter must be empty " displays in the run output results.

I'm using the below lines of code :

```
web_add_filter("Action=Exclude", "PathPrefix=/css/", LAST );
web_add_filter("Action=Exclude", "PathPrefix=/js", LAST );
web_add_filter("Action=Exclude", "PathPrefix=/images/1033", LAST );
web_add_filter("Action=Exclude", "PathPrefix=/aka", LAST );
```

Comment: Could you provide more details on LR version + protocols + maybe more of the script.

Comment: I currently work on LR 11.5 using web http/html protocol.
the script were run successfully before adding the WEb_add_filter lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

There is no hostname context to which the pathprefix would be applied.

Also, the context of these items would be the next call only.   It is very unusual to deliberately be excluding style sheets, javascript, images, etc... from downloading.    This may indicate that the cache aging is not set correctly for these mime types on the web server or that the developers have used a no-cache method as a part of the request.